# Different Slicers for Different Visualizations in PowerBI

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis, powerbi

I am very new to Power BI.

Let's say I have a data containing student's English proficiency tests. The name of the data is `EnglishScores`. The columns inside this data are `Listening`, `Writing`, `Speaking`, and `StudentIDs`. I created a measurement called `StudentGrade` from the `StudentID` to differentiate them based on which grades they are on (fourth grade, fifth grade, and sixth grade).
I want to create three visualizations for each of the scores (total number of viz: 3) and slicers for each of these visualizations as well (3 slicers) based on the student grades.

I successfully create a visualization and slicer for the `Listening` column. But the problem is that when I create another slicer from the `StudentGrade` for the other scores, it links to the previous slicers and visualizations.
How can I make new slicers filter certain visualizations?

Thank you

Comment: See if this (https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-visual-interactions) works.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you need by editing the interaction settings for the filters and visualizations.

Assuming you're using Power BI Desktop:
In short, select a slicer and click the "Edit" button in the Visual Interactions group on the ribbon menu. You can probably figure it out from there, or check this video for more details. You'll just repeat that for each filter/visualization combo you'd like to adjust.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_xYsCbyHPw

Here's a page with written instructions if you prefer that to the video:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-visual-interactions/